# Check which index a custom object in NSArray has

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray

A really simple question here.
I know how do you check if an NSString exists in an array and I do it like this:

```
if ([dataArray containsObject:paymentMethodString])
```

But apart from checking if it *exists* or not I would like to find out the *index* of corresponding element in the array. How do you do that in Objective-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
NSUInteger index = [dataArray indexOfObject:your_object];
```

Comment: You should not use a `NSString` as a param. But the object himself.

Comment: @PKCoder I most certainly will, after 12 minutes. StackOverflow doesn't allow me to :(

Answer (score 3):

```
NSUInteger index = [dataArray indexOfObject:paymentMethodString];

if( index != NSNotFound ) {

    //the object is present at the index
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[dataArray indexOfObject:paymentMethodString]
```

Answer (score 1):

use NSArray method:

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject
```

like this:

```
NSUInteger myIndex = [dataArray indexOfObject:paymentMethodString];
```